# How to Sort PHP Array by Key/Value For "Lastname, Firstname"?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I've got an array like:

```
$players[124] = array(
    'name'   => 'Moss, Randy'
    'number' => 84
);

$players[864] = array(
    'name'   => 'Carter, Chris',
    'number' => 80
);
```

I want to sort the array by last name AND first name. All I have to work with in the array is "Lastname, Firstname".

This is the sorting method I THOUGHT would produces desired results, however, it doesn't seem to do the trick. Why doesn't this work? What can I do to make this work?

```
uksort( $players, function ( $a, $b ) {
    return strcasecmp( $a['name'], $b['name'] );
} );
```

Comment: Just `usort`, without `k`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `usort` instead of `uksort`:

```
usort( $players, function ( $a, $b ) {
    return strcasecmp( $a['name'], $b['name'] );
} );
```

If you want to maintain key association, use `uasort`:

```
uasort( $players, function ( $a, $b ) {
    return strcasecmp( $a['name'], $b['name'] );
} );
```

Comment: I need to maintain the keys of each player. Wouldn't `usort` eliminate those keys?

Comment: Wow I feel stupid now. I used the wrong one. Thanks sorry for wasting your time.